# Thymeleaf URL Get Parameter

Tags: url, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf and would like to extract the service parameter from the URL in my browser:

```
 http://www.company.com/index.php?service=http://www.abcdef.com/
```

How would I get the service parameter and store them as variables:

I want to get the ***http://*** part and store it into a variable
I want to get the ***www.abcdef.com*** and store it into a variable
I want to get the ***http://www.abcdef.com*** and store it into a variable

Comment: You can get the URL using `{#httpServletRequest.requestURI}`.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan thanks. I have used ${#request.getParameter('service')} instead

Answer (score 0):

At time of writing and given this URL...

```
http://localhost:8080/employees/list?managerId=1&page=0
```

...I wanted to construct a link to the next page. Here's how I did it...

```
<span th:if="${page.hasNext()}">
    <a th:href="@{''(managerId=${param.managerId},page=${page.number+1})}">Next</a>
</span>
```

All of which yields this URL...

```
http://localhost:8080/employees/list?managerId=1&page=1
```

It's the ${param.name} that does the trick. Luck.